# Making of Custom Langchain Agent that acts as a Coach or a Teacher

Tags: python, agent, langchain

I have a vector store in Qdrant. Now, I aim to develop a custom langchain agent that is conversational and provides context based on a specific topic to the user. The agent will then generate questions from the context in the vector store and ask the user to answer. If the user provides an answer, it will be evaluated, and the agent will suggest improvements if necessary. If the user's answer meets a certain satisfaction level, the agent will also present quizzes. Essentially, this agent acts like a coach or a teacher, instructing, asking questions, and administering quizzes based on the context in the vector store.

I tried to customize the agent but failed to do so.

I was only able to retrieve the vector store.

```py
load_dotenv()

def get_vectorstore():
  client = qdrant_client.QdrantClient(
        os.getenv("QDRANT_HOST"),
        api_key=os.getenv("QDRANT_API_KEY")
  )
  embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
  vectorstore = Qdrant(
        client=client,
        collection_name=os.getenv("QDRANT_COLLECTION"),
        embeddings=embeddings
  )
  return vectorstore
vectorstore = get_vectorstore()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.